# Generators of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{11}$

Tags: group-theory

My task was to find all groups of order 55 and then describe each of them with generators. I found that there is only 1 abelian group, $\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{11}$. I don't know how to find generators of this group. Any hints?

P.S.  Also I found that there is only 1 non-abelian group with generators: $G = C _ { 11 } \times _ { \phi } C _ { 5 } = \langle x , y | x ^ { 11 } = 1 , y ^ { 3 } = 1 , y x = x ^ { 4 } y \rangle$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{55}}$.

Comment: So: $x ^ { 11 } = 1 , y ^ { 5 } = 1 , y x y ^ { - 1 } = x ^ { r } , \text { for some } r , 1 \leq r < 11$?

Comment: You wrote your task was to find all the groups of order $55$ up to isomorphism. So instead of $\mathbb{Z_5}\times\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ you can take the group $\mathbb{Z_{55}}$ as they are isomorphic according to the Chinese remainder theorem. And it is obvious that $\mathbb{Z_{55}}=\langle 1\rangle$. If for some reason you still want to work with $\mathbb{Z_5}\times\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ you can prove the element $(1,1)$ has order $55$, hence generates the whole group.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with $\Bbb Z_{55}$ and there will be $\varphi (55)=40$ generators, corresponding to integers coprime with $55$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $5$ and $11$ are relatively prime, the element $(1_5, 1_{11})$ will generate $\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_{11}$